# Cómo graficar con python la solución de un problema de localización

Tags: python, visualización-de-datos

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de localización sin capacidades. Lo que tengo que hacer es abrir plantas de producción y asignar a clientes a dichas plantas de forma que el gasto total sea mínimo, ya que abrir plantas (o mantener las que están abiertas) tiene coste y asignar clientes a dichas plantas de producción tiene otro coste.
Este problema lo he programado y resuelto. Y obtuve los siguientes resultados:
Trabajo con 5 dimensiones:

- Costes de asignar los clientes a las plantas:
  `[[18, 73, 98, 9, 33], [16, 64, 98, 58, 61], [84, 49, 27, 13, 63], [4, 50, 56, 78, 98], [99, 1, 90, 58, 35]]` (por ejemplo, en la planta 0 el cliente 0 tiene un costo de 18, y en la planta 2 tiene un costo de 84).
- Coste de abrir o mantener abiertas las plantas de producción: `[93, 30, 76, 14, 41]`

Con el script que he programado obtengo que:

- A la planta de producción 3 que vale 14 euros, mandaremos al:
  cliente 0 por 4 euros y al cliente 2 por 56 euros.
- A la planta de producción 4 que vale 41 euros, mandaremos al:
  cliente 1 por 1 euros, al cliente 3 por 58 euros y al cliente 4 por 35 euros.

De esta forma, la inversión nuestra es mínima: 290 euros, de todas las posibles.

Tanto los costes que genero, como la dimensión del problema es aleatoria y a cada vez que ejecuto el programa se genera una dimensión y costos distintos. Por ejemplo, si ejecuto el programa y obtengo dimensión 3, entonces tendré tres plantas de producción, 3 clientes y también tendré otros costos.

Mi problema es que he de mostrar la solución de forma gráfica y no tengo idea de cómo hacerlo. ¿Hay alguna forma?
Gracias

Comment: En resumen, tienes un juego de datos que deseas mostrar en forma gráfica. ¿Cual forma gráfica? ¿Un mapa, un diagrama de bloques, un gráfico de torta? Es mejor que replantees la pregunta mostrando los datos de que dispones y la gráfica que deseas obtener. Toda la explicación de clientes, plantas y costes no tiene relación los gráficos.

Answer (score 0):

Una posible visualización de los datos (entre las muchas que serían posibles) sería:

- Hacer un gráfico de barras en el que cada barra representa una planta, y la altura de la barra es el coste total de esa planta
- Dividir cada barra en franjas de modo que cada franja represente el coste fijo, y el de cada uno de los clientes que se hayan asignado a esa planta
- Se puede añadir además una tabla que sirva a la vez de leyenda y de resumen de todos los datos.

Es decir, siguiendo estas ideas la visualización de la solución que pones en la pregunta sería la siguiente:

[image: Grafica]

Como ves, esta gráfica muestra las cinco plantas, si bien las tres primeras están vacías. La tabla ayuda a visualizar claramente las asignaciones, y las barras dan una idea de la magnitud de los costes.

Es posible también eliminar las plantas que no tienen cliente asignado, dejando sólo las que sí lo tengan:

[image: Grafico 2]

### Como hacerlo

Para empezar es necesario recoger la información que la gráfica debe mostrar en algún tipo de estructura de datos. Propongo un array bidimensional como el siguiente:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Datos de entrada, cada fila es una planta
data = np.array(
    [
        [93, 30, 76, 14, 41],       # Costes fijos de cada planta
        [ 0,  0,  0,  4,  0],       # Costes de asignar cliente 0
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1],       # Costes de asignar cliente 1
        [ 0,  0,  0, 56,  0],       # Costes de asignar cliente 2
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 58],       # Costes de asignar cliente 3
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 35],       # Costes de asignar cliente 3
    ])
```

Ves que el coste de asignar clientes se ha dejado sólo en la planta a la que ha sido asignado. Los demás son ceros. Los costes fijos de cada planta los he dejado como referencia, pero en realidad deberían ser cero también para las plantas cerradas.

Esto podemos arreglarlo así:

```
# Preparación previa de los datos anteriores. En las plantas en que
# no haya clientes asignados, se pone el coste fijo a 0
data[0] = [data[0,i]*any(data[1:, i]) for i in range(data.shape[1])]
```

Una vez tenemos los datos preparados, las gráficas anteriores se obtendrían con el siguiente código, que no voy a explicar en detalle por no alargar la respuesta (pero que está suficientemente comentado como para que pueda entenderse)

```
# La siguiente variable permite elegir si queremos quitar de la gráfica
# las plantas que no tengan clientes asignados, como en la segunda figura
# o dejarlas como en la primera
quitar_vacias = True

num_plantas = data.shape[1]
num_clients = data.shape[0]-1

# Nombres de las plantas
plantas = ["Planta {}".format(i) for i in range(num_plantas)]

# Nombres de los clientes
clientes = ["Cliente {}".format(i) for i in range(num_clients)] 

# Nombres de las filas de la tabla inferior
nombres_filas = ["Coste fijo"] + clientes + ["Total"]

# Elegir un color diferente para cada franja (y fila de la tabla inferior)
colores = plt.cm.Accent(np.linspace(0, 1, len(nombres_filas)))

# Opcional. Quitar las columnas de la tabla que sumen 0
if quitar_vacias:
  elegidas = data.sum(axis=0)>0
  data = data[:, elegidas]
  plantas = np.array(plantas)[elegidas]
  num_plantas = len(plantas)

index = np.arange(num_plantas) + 0.3
bar_width = 0.4

# Para hacer las barras "apiladas" hay que recordar el valor "top" de cada
# columna. Inicialmente todas comienzan en cero
y_offset = np.zeros(len(plantas))

# Para generar una tabla debajo preparamos una lista con lo que deberá
# mostrarse en cada fila de esa tabla
cell_text = []

# Creamos cada "franja" (y fila en la tabla)
for fila in range(len(data)):
    # Pintar esta franja en todas las columnas
    plt.bar(index, data[fila], bar_width, bottom=y_offset, color=colores[fila])

    # Actualizar el "top" de cada columna
    y_offset = y_offset + data[fila]
    
    # Actualizar fila de la tabla final
    cell_text.append([str(x) if x else "-" for x in data[fila]])

# Añadir a la tabla final una última fila con los "Totales" por planta
cell_text.append([str(total) for total in np.array(data).sum(axis=0)])

the_table = plt.table(cellText=cell_text,
                      rowLabels=nombres_filas,
                      rowColours=colores,
                      colLabels=plantas,
                      loc='bottom')

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.2)

plt.ylabel("Costes")
plt.xticks([])
plt.title('Coste total {}'.format(np.array(data).sum()))
plt.gcf().set_size_inches((6,6))
```